# Algorithm : Why do I need to reassign an array element to a variable?

Tags: arrays, algorithm

pretty new to algorithms here. I began watching Princeton's Algorithms and Data Structures class when the professor gave this code:

```
public void  union(int p, int q){

int pid = id[p];
int qid = id[q];

for(int i = 0; i <id.length; i++){
if (id[i] = pid)
  id[i] = qid;
}
```

He said that you need to first assign id[p] to pid. Why is that? Why couldn't you just use id[p]? Also, I started reading Introduction to Algorithms and saw this implementation of insertion sort. I noticed that instead of just using A[j] they assigned that to 'key'. Is it for the same reason as the one above? Thanks!

```
INSERTION-SORT.A/
1 for j = 2 to A.length
2 key = A[j]
4 i = j - 1
5 while i>0 and A(i) > key{
6 A(i+1) = A(i)
7 i=i-1}
8 A[i+1] = key
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to copy that element into a temporary variable because the value will be overwritten in a later stage of the algorithm.

Consider your suggested version:

```
for(int i = 0; i <id.length; i++){
    if (id[i] == id[p]) {
        id[i] = id[q];
    }
}
```

When `i` equals `p`, then `id[p]` will be overwritten by the value of `id[q]`. The original `id[p]` now forgotten, the rest of the algorithm will produce erroneous results. Try it out!

And yes, in the insertion sort we need to save the original value of A[j] for the same reason: the element value overwritten, we'd lose the the original value otherwise.